# how to give a specific name to an email address in postfix.?

Tags: open-source, monitoring, nagios, postfix-mta

i installed Nagios core on my system which sends me an email if some service goes into Critical/warning stage. everything is working fine.
I have configures post-fix to send out an email and configured an email address in "`sasl_passwd`" file something like this "`[smtp.gmail.com]:587 <email-id>:<password>`".
when i receive a mail about service stage it comes as a "Alert from `<email-id>`" now i want to change that i want an email to come as "Nagios alert" or something like that in mail subject rather than just `<email-id>` showing.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your commands `notify-host-by-email` and `notify-service-by-email`. These commands are what sends the email notification. It pipes a message string to `/bin/mail` by default. It already includes the `-s` flag indicating the subject. So in order to overwrite the sender, we check `man mail` and determine that the flag is `-r [from-addr]`. So, you can change your commands from:

```
# 'notify-host-by-email' command definition
define command{
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }

# 'notify-service-by-email' command definition
define command{
    command_name    notify-service-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

To:

```
# 'notify-host-by-email' command definition
define command{
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /bin/mail -r "someemail@somewhere.com" -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }

# 'notify-service-by-email' command definition
define command{
    command_name    notify-service-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /bin/mail -r "someemail@somewhere.com" -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

Where **someemail@somewhere.com** is your email address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if i just want "Nagios" name?

Comment: Then specify this as the `-r` flag: `-r "Nagios Alerts <nagios@yourdomain.com>"`